# Space between element and text in html

Tags: html, css, sass, less

While writing html, the element has padding zero and margin is zero, but there are spaces around the text. How can I destroy it?
[image]

line height etc. I tried features but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide the html?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mre]. See [ask] and [tour] if you need any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the page's default stylings before styling mentioned elements?

I think that may be the issue.

**Before start styling of your page it is a best practice to remove all the styles and uniforming the default look first.**

I've been using the code below for all of my projects up to this point.

```
  *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }
```

This will remove basic stylings for the whole webpage.Copy and paste the above code into your CSS file.

If this is not the case, you need to add the **line-height** property to your h1 tag. Here is the snippet given below.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  background-color:lightblue;
  margin-top: 0px;
  line-height: 75%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Transitional<br>Heroes<h1/>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the page default styling.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll save you **ton of time** to start any of your projects with the below css codes.

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, HTML includes certain styles in the different tags.
To create a project from scratch, it is advisable to use a CSS reset file. The community has created several.
These files reset all the default styles of HTML and the different variants between browsers to achieve the same visual result in the most popular browsers on the market.

Here is a CSS reset offered by the user karbassi through GitHub:

https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6